# Batch script renaming TIFF to a number

Tags: batch-file, rename

I need to create a script to rename hundreds of TIF files in a folder to a five digit number with leading zeros. For example, 00001, 00002, 00003, etc. I would also like to set the start number. I have very little scripting experience and don't know where to start. Thanks for the help.

Comment: please improved your question. What you have done so far

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this in Python, which is available on most OSes. Here's a Python script to rename all the TIF files in the current directory:

```
import os

i = 1
for tifFile in [a for a in os.listdir('.') if a.endswith('.tif')]:
    newFileName = "%05d.tif" % i
    os.rename(tifFile,newFileName)
    i = i + 1
```

You'll want to note that the behaviour of os.rename() can be different on different operating systems -- on some OSes it will overwrite an existing file with the same name as the new file. On others it will cause an error if there is an existing file with the same name as the new file.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set startnum=1
for %%a in (*.tif) do (
if !startnum! lss 10 ren "%%a" 0000!startnum!.* && set /a startnum+=1
if !startnum! lss 100 if !startnum! geq 10 ren "%%a" 000!startnum!.* && set /a startnum+=1
if !startnum! lss 1000 if !startnum! geq 100 ren "%%a" 00!startnum!.* && set /a startnum+=1
if !startnum! lss 10000 if !startnum! geq 1000 ren "%%a" 0!startnum!.* && set /a startnum+=1
if !startnum! lss 100000 if !startnum! geq 10000 ren "%%a" !startnum!.* && set /a startnum+=1
)
```

Plus, if you only have hundreds of files you could even get rid of the `if`'s after 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Put the initial number minus one in the parameter, the default is zero:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set num=00000%1
set num=1%num:~-5%
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.tif') do (
   set /A num+=1
   ren "%%a" "!num:~-5!.tif"
)
```